# Run SalesforceSDKManager on button click

Tags: android, salesforce-sdk-android

I’ve managed to make the whole integration working, but I wanna modify it according to our business process. I have been working on this for days now but I’m still nowhere near completion. Here’s the problem: once I run the app, it should not redirect to salesforce login page yet. It should go first to an Activity where I put a button. Once clicked, that’s the time it should proceed to the login page. I can’t seem to get this part working.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".RestIntent"
    android:manageSpaceActivity="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.ManageSpaceActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainIntent"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainIntent" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

RestIntent.java

```
public class RestIntent extends Application {

public static Context context;
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

public void buttonclick(){
        SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(context, new KeyImpl(), MainIntent.class);
}
}
```

My MainActivity.java has a function for handling button click:

```
public void salesforce(View view){
    RestIntent app = (RestIntent)getApplication();
    app.buttonclick();
}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. I think there is something amiss here. Hope you can help.

Thanks.